# Inline using how to make use of it

Tags: c#, using, using-statement, using-declaration

In C# one can type the using verb in line width the code sometimes, like

> using (textwriter){ ..... }

I like  that writing style and am wondered what is required to allow that for my own Api's.

Comment: It's not just a fancy style of coding, it's here for the specific reason – managed resources handling. Instances of types, implementing `IDisposable` interface, should be disposed with use of `Dispose` invocation. `using` statement is a convenient way to guarantee that `Dispose` will be actually called. See this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Answer (score 0):

As long as your objects are IDisposable then you can use it with the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).